# WSO2 ESB Multiple instances of proxy service

Tags: wso2, ibm-mq

We are using WSO2 ESB and as transport we have WebSphere MQ which is accessed using JMS.
Problem is that each proxy service works in one thread with WebSphere MQ and because of that we have performance issues.
How can we start multiple instances of proxy service without deploying multiple copies of it? Maybe there are some hidden configuration parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to already mentioned parameter

```
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConcurrentConsumers">2</parameter>
```

you might need to add another one:

```
<parameter name="transport.jms.IdleTaskLimit">2147483647</parameter>
```

This parameter represents number of idle message read attempts per thread. When counter of such idle read attempts becomes equal to this parameter, the thread stops reading messages (if it is not the only reader).

Given that, setting this parameter to the upper limit of java int provides you with virtually infinite reading by all the threads.

Answer (score 1):

You should define this parameter in your proxy conf :

```
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConcurrentConsumers">2</parameter>
```

WSO2 use one consumer by default

Have a look there : http://mmalithh.blogspot.fr/2013_05_01_archive.html

Comment: When we are changing this parameter (on axis2-level or proxy-level, or both) it seems to be working during WSO2 ESB startup. But after startup finished we have only one listener on queue. What can be a reason for this behaviour?

Comment: If you have multiple proxys, perhaps do you reach the max threads (20) in the JMS base transport worker pool, have you tried to add a JMS.properties with snd_t_core, etc. ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to add JMS.properties file with no success.