# How to use the same WSO2 ESB server to consume MQ messages in multi-threading

Tags: jms, wso2, esb

I am using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 to consume MQ messages via MQ bindings-file connection. I would like to know how to configure WSO2 ESB properly in multi-threading mode, i.e. using multiple JMS MDB listeners or consumers, on the same ESB server runtime instance.

I have tested the option of using

```
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConcurrentConsumers">2</parameter>
```

at the proxy service level but this solution only works during ESB server startup. After ESB server has been started and then stays in idle, the number of JMS consumers drops back to 1. Please note that my ESB server only has one JMS proxy service deployed and loaded.

Deploying the exactly same proxy service multiple times with a different name would work, but it is not an option I would like.

[WSO2 ESB Multiple instances of proxy service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180364/wso2-esb-multiple-instances-of-proxy-service)

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Following this link you can see a solution which does NOT require multiple deploy.  Have you tried this parameter (transport.jms.IdleTaskLimit) as described?

Comment: Please note that the referenced link reported the same issue that I have encountered and no resolution is found at this point.

Comment: Have you checked the accepted answer there? And have you tried to use IdleTaskLimit parameter?